# If $P(Y^{2} \geq k) = 0.95$ is it true that $P(\sqrt{k} \leq Y \leq 1) =0.95$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable defined on $[0,1]$, and that we know $Y^{2} \sim \mathrm{unif}[0,1]$.

Suppose I determine the value of $k$ for which $P(Y^{2} \geq k) = 0.95$.

Would it be correct to say that $$P(\sqrt{k} \leq Y \leq 1) =0.95$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $Y$ is non-negative so the event $\{Y^2\geq k\}$ is equivalent to $\{\sqrt{k}\leq Y\leq 1\}$

Answer (score 0):

For general $Y$ and $k>0$, 
$$ P(Y^2\ge k)=P(Y\ge \sqrt k\lor Y\le -\sqrt k)=P(Y\ge \sqrt k)+P(Y\le -\sqrt k)$$
By your condition on $Y$, $P(Y<0)=0$, hence the second summand can be dropped, and $P(Y>1)=0$, hence the other summand can be replaced with $P(\sqrt k \le Y\le 1)$, indeed.